# How to print elements in a vector of vectors

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of vectors, and I want to print elements in each vector

I tried the pprint but did not work as wanted

This is the vector of vectors I wish to print:

```
[["+" "+" "+" "#" "!" "-" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"]
 ["!" "#" "+" "+" "+" "#" "+" "+" "+" "-" "#" "#" "-"]
 ["#" "#" "#" "#" "+" "#" "+" "#" "+" "#" "-" "#" "#"]
 ["+" "+" "+" "#" "+" "+" "+" "#" "+" "#" "-" "-" "-"]
 ["+" "#" "+" "#" "#" "#" "#" "+" "+" "-" "#" "#" "-"]
 ["+" "#" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"]
 ["+" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#"]
 ["+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "@"]]
```

This is the output I want:

```
+++#--###--#-
!#+++#+++-##-
####+#+#+#!##
+++#+++#+#!!!
+#+####++!##!
+#++++++#!!!!
+############
++++++++++++@
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and add the errors you got or problems you faced.

Comment: we seem to be attempting to solve this maze homework tiny piece by tiny piece, whether it’s the same person under multiple aliases or not. my recommendation is that you check out some of the basic clojure tutorials rather than iteratively spam SO. you will get there quicker and learn faster. iirc The Joy of Clojure has a full A* maze solver which is amazingly presented.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [cl-format](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format) to handle list (and list of list in this case) with a control string:

```clj
(def input
  [["+" "+" "+" "#" "!" "-" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"]
   ["!" "#" "+" "+" "+" "#" "+" "+" "+" "-" "#" "#" "-"]
   ["#" "#" "#" "#" "+" "#" "+" "#" "+" "#" "-" "#" "#"]
   ["+" "+" "+" "#" "+" "+" "+" "#" "+" "#" "-" "-" "-"]
   ["+" "#" "+" "#" "#" "#" "#" "+" "+" "-" "#" "#" "-"]
   ["+" "#" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"]
   ["+" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#"]
   ["+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "@"]])

(use 'clojure.pprint)

(cl-format *out* "~{~{~a~}~%~}" input)
```

**Output:**

```clj
+++#!-###----
!#+++#+++-##-
####+#+#+#-##
+++#+++#+#---
+#+####++-##-
+#++++++#----
+############
++++++++++++@
```

**Explanation:**
`~a` is the format argument of any type.  When enclosed in `~{` and `~}`, the format argument will be iterated over a list.  So when enclosed twice with `~{` and `~}`, `~a` will be applied over each element (character) in the nested list.  The `~%` before the last `~}` is to output a newline.
With this, you can easily change the output with control string.  For example:

```clj
(cl-format *out* "~{~{(~a)~^ ~}~^~%~%~}" input)

(+) (+) (+) (#) (!) (-) (#) (#) (#) (-) (-) (-) (-)

(!) (#) (+) (+) (+) (#) (+) (+) (+) (-) (#) (#) (-)

(#) (#) (#) (#) (+) (#) (+) (#) (+) (#) (-) (#) (#)

(+) (+) (+) (#) (+) (+) (+) (#) (+) (#) (-) (-) (-)

(+) (#) (+) (#) (#) (#) (#) (+) (+) (-) (#) (#) (-)

(+) (#) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (#) (-) (-) (-) (-)

(+) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#) (#)

(+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (+) (@)
```

Note that "`~^`" is the directive to stop iteration when a list is run out. So "`~^<space>`" will suppress the space after the last element in each line.  And "`~^~%~%`" will suppress the double newline after the last line.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any fancy formatting or side-effects (although I do appreciate the information in those answers). Just use `clojure.string/join` to create the string you want and print it any old way.

```
> (join "\n" (map join input))
+++#!-###----
!#+++#+++-##-
####+#+#+#-##
+++#+++#+#---
+#+####++-##-
+#++++++#----
+############
++++++++++++@
```

e.g.

```
> (let [s (join "\n" (map join input))] (println s))
+++#!-###----
!#+++#+++-##-
####+#+#+#-##
+++#+++#+#---
+#+####++-##-
+#++++++#----
+############
++++++++++++@
nil
```

Comment: that is the perfect solution. (let [s (string/join "\n" (map string/join a))] (println s))
this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use [run!](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!) to go over the outer vector and [clojure.string/join](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join) to turn each inner vector into a printable string.

Assuming your vector is defined as `input`:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
(run! (comp println str/join) input)
```